# Cant launch jar file built with Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a project in eclipse which uses ant to both compile and to jar the class files and referenced jars. The jar files generated using  the class files generated by the default java builder in eclipse work fine, but when using ant to compile the source and then jar the results, the error "Error: An unexpected error occured while trying to open file .......jar" results while executing java -jar on the target build. Anyone know what im doing wrong? below is the build xml contents. Here are the arguments I pass to ant

-DInTouchV.SrcPath=${InTouchV.SrcPath} -DInTouchV.DropPath=${workspace_loc:/InTouchVTransferService/dist}

```
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project InTouchVTransferService">
<!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard-->
<!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->
<property name="Version" value="1.3"></property> 
<tstamp>
    <format property="TODAY" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
</tstamp>
<target name="Compile_Source">
    <javac srcdir="${InTouchV.SrcPath}/InTouchVTransferService/src"
                     destdir="${InTouchV.SrcPath}/InTouchVTransferService/bin"
                     classpath="${InTouchV.SrcPath}/lib/AtomClasses.jar"
                     debug="on"
                    includeantruntime="yes"
                    /> 
</target>
<target name="create_run_jar">
    <mkdir dir="${InTouchV.SrcPath}/InTouchVTransferService/bin"/>     
    <jar destfile="${InTouchV.DropPath}/InTouchVTransferClient.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.emdat.inTouchV.main.Main"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
            <section name="common">
                <attribute name="Build-Version" value="${Version}"/>
                <attribute name="Build-Date" value="${TODAY}"/>
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
                <attribute name="JVM Version" value="${java.runtime.name} - ${java.runtime.version}" />
            </section>
        </manifest>
        <fileset dir="${InTouchV.SrcPath}/InTouchVTransferService/bin"/>
        <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="${InTouchV.SrcPath}/lib/AtomClasses.jar"/>
    </jar>
    <touch file="${InTouchV.DropPath}/Version.txt" />
    <echo file="${InTouchV.DropPath}/Version.txt">${Version}</echo>
</target>
</project>
```

Comment: You may be having a async issue in which the jar process isn't finished before you try to do stuff. You may want to do some logging and see where its blowing up more... and provide that info too.

Comment: I have winmerge compared the two zip files and appart from the obvious (timestamp in the version .txt) the files were identical :(. All of the class files are present, and the manifest looks correct. Ill try moving the javac task out ot a different target

Comment: Running the compile step as a seperate  target, before the jar set didnt solve any issues :(

Comment: For what its worth, the java API source for ZipFile (called by the jar file child class) gives that message when a general IO exception is encountered, but I can open the jar file in 7zip just fine. Netbeans can also parse the jar file without any issues.

Comment: I ran ant with verbose output, ntohing in the output seems suspect from what I can see, and I cant post the output here... its to large for the maximum post size for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, the attribute "JVM Version" contains a space. Removed the space, jar files execute correctly. I honestly couldnt say why the default java builder for eclipse + ant jar worked with the space, but ant build + ant jar didnt. At least its fixed :D